# Boolean single on/off field - how to make it NOT render the off option?

Tags: entities

I'm having some issues with boolean field. I want to have few fields that can be turned on/off, which will be used to show if something is available in the content.

So I thought single on/off checkbox is the way to go. Well, apparently not because even if I don't select the checkboxes, they're still rendered in the code. And I need them to NOT render.

Checkboxes/radio buttons works in this way, but it creates 3 selectable options (on, off, not available) whether I would like to have only one checkbox.

I also tried using List (text) for my needs, but here I'm limited by the fact I can't add individual CSS id/classes to every item in the list.

My target is using these lists/checkboxes, hidding them in CSS and replacing with icons. I did something like this few months ago but now I can't remember how exactly I achieved what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out field of the List (text) type was enough, just needed to create my own field template for that field. With this I was able to render additional classes/id and change the way the field is build, making it possible to style as needed using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them either through CSS or you can unset them using the form_alter if you are using forms. Look at the code below 
In this code, I am unsetting the author on the comment form.

```
function Mymodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'comment_form) {
      unset($form['author']);
    }
  }
}
```

If you've added the field to some node then you can unset them using this code.

```
unset($node->field);
```